# When is it possible to add different powers of a dimensioned quantity?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, symplectic-geometry

When is it possible to add different powers of a dimensioned (i.e. non-dimensionless) quantity, e.g. consider power series for dimensioned quantities. For example, when can you exponentiate a dimensioned quantity? I have heard that this is done in symplectic geometry (e.g. $e^\omega$) but I don't know any more beyond this.

Comment: I suppose you can do anything you want, but in this case it’ll probably be meaningless, at least from a physical or geometric standpoint.

Comment: What if $\omega$ is a symplectic form, then does $e^\omega$ make sense?

Comment: I've made the change.

Comment: Why was this question closed as a duplicate? The other question doesn't address at all the problem of taking the exponential of a symplectic form

Comment: Is the question currently visible? It's showing as a duplicate to me (even though the other question doesn't address my question, as you pointed out).